# How many teams and team members are involved in making this SO network

Tags: discussion

I wonder SO is just a sister website. The SO network website is growing day by day. The Database as well as the network bandwidth will also be huge.

How many teams are working in maintaining this huge network of websites (approx)? I am just curious to know. Trust me I have no intentions of copying this website network.

Comment: [StackExchange Team](http://stackexchange.com/about/team)

Comment: Why would we suspect you wanted to make an SO clone based on asking how many people work on the site? Is there some new "throw exactly as many people at a problem as some other company" design pattern now?

Comment: For info, various aspects of the technical infrastructure (databases, network bandwidth, etc) are discussed on [the SF blog](http://blog.serverfault.com/) and [here on meta.SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-are-used-to-build-the-stack-exchange-network)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are the workers of Stack Exchange: https://stackexchange.com/about/team (68 people)

These are the moderators of Stack Exchange: https://stackexchange.com/about/moderators (341 moderators right now)

You can see site specific moderators in each site's users page e.g. [Stack Overflow moderators](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators).

Comment: There are a few more that have not yet been added to the team page (or gotten a blog post)... We are closer to 80 now.

Comment: @Oded The remaining 12 have got compensatory ponies?

Comment: Or Unicorns? :D

Comment: @Ren I bet they get free T-shirts!

Comment: @Oded beautiful team members for Sales and marketing ! its amazing that just 80 peoples have made this beautiful logical website.